# PHPMailer: Don't understand the from address

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to learn PHPMailer and I don't understand why it needs an email address and password.

```
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
```

It's not coming from a persons email, it's coming from the site. What email am I supposed to put here and why?

Comment: you are attempting to use `SMTP` to send the email, when you do this you need to login to the `SMTP` server with a valid username and password.  You can change this line `$mail->isSMTP();` to `$mail->isMail();` to send it though the built in mail functions.

Comment: So, if I change it to `ismail();` I can leave the password and username and all of that blank?

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples

Comment: If you use `isMail` you don't need all of the SMTP-related settings, but it will use whatever "From" address your PHP config is set to use, or fall back to a default, probably something like `www-data@server123.example.com`. Messages must come from an address or they won't have anywhere to be returned to if they fail to be delivered.

Answer (score 0):

The email address is the address which the emails are sent from.  The username and password are required for SMTP servers that require authentication in order to send mail.

Answer (score 0):

The way email works is that party 1 has an email account which it uses to send mail to party 2. Party 1 can be a site, a person, a script or something else, but it still needs to have an email account to be able to send email.

This is the way SMTP (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol) [has been defined](http://cr.yp.to/smtp/mail.html), and you need to follow the definitions of that protocol to get your mail delivered.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to provide password -

```
<?php 
require("class.phpmailer.php"); 
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "smtp.example.com"; // SMTP server 
$mail->From     = "example@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress("example@gmail.com"); 
$mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";
$mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";
$mail->WordWrap = 50; 
if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Message was not sent.';
echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
?>
```

[Click here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mail.php)

Comment: It's not necessary to use a password if you're using an open relay, but in all other circumstances, you will need one. Also, you've based your code on an obsolete example and are using an old version of PHPMailer.